# Ошибка Action has more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from request body

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Есть такая странная ошибка при добавлении api контроллера в работающий проект: собирается, но при старте проекта выдаёт вместо индексной страницы сайта ошибку:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> InvalidOperationException: Action
> 'WebApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers.CityApiController.All (WebApp)' has
> more than one parameter that was specified or inferred as bound from
> request body. Only one parameter per action may be bound from body.
>
> Inspect the following parameters, and use 'FromQueryAttribute' to
> specify bound from query, 'FromRouteAttribute' to specify bound from
> route, and 'FromBodyAttribute' for parameters to be bound from body:
> Query query CancellationToken cancellationToken
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.InferParameterBindingSources(ActionModel
> actionModel)

Контроллер совершенно рядовой, у меня в другом проекте практически такой же работает без проблем:

```
public class CityApiController : AdminApiControllerBase
{
    public CityApiController(IMediator mediator)
        : base(mediator)
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<object> All(Cities.List.Query query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await this.Mediator.Send(query, cancellationToken);
        return result;
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
public class AdminApiControllerBase : Controller
{
    public AdminApiControllerBase(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.Mediator = mediator ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(mediator));
    }

    protected readonly IMediator Mediator;
}
```

Что это может быть такое? Хочется понять и разобраться. На новичковую [ошибку](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50552702/net-core-web-api-multiple-frombody) не похоже.

Answer (score 4):

Нашёл любопытный баг на гитхабе: [ApiControllerAttribute incorrectly infers CancellationToken parameter as FromBody](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7781)

В двух словах: поведение для FromBody разнится для 2.0 и 2.1 поэтому необходимо явно выставлять режим совместимости:

```
services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Проект, который не запускался, был как раз проектом 2.0, многократно переделанном и потом переведённом на 2.1